# Ternary Plot using a vector as density

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ternary

I have a dataset like this:

```
DENSE<-runif(10, min=0, max=100)
CROP<-runif(10, min=0, max=100)
WILD<-runif(10, min=0, max=100)
BetaDiv<-runif(10, min=0, max=1)
df<-data.frame(DENSE, CROP, WILD, BetaDiv)
```

I use this code to do a simple ternary plot,

```
ggtern(df[ordered(-df$BetaDiv),],aes(DENSE,CROP,WILD))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.8, aes(color=BetaDiv), size=3)+ scale_color_viridis_c(direction = -1)+
  stat_density_tern(geom = 'polygon',
                    n         = 100,
                    aes(fill  = ..level..,
                        alpha = ..level..))
```

[Ternary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7xP5.png)

However, I need the density to be given by the variable BetaDiv. That is, that the density shows me where the BetaDiv values are concentrated.

Thanks to every one.

RS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify it through `aes(value=...)` and I would think a hex would make more sense, where it basically cuts your plot into hex bins and calculates the sum of your beta values within each bin.

```
set.seed(111)
DENSE<-runif(20, min=0, max=100)
CROP<-runif(20, min=0, max=100)
WILD<-runif(20, min=0, max=100)
BetaDiv<-runif(20, min=0, max=1)
df<-data.frame(DENSE, CROP, WILD, BetaDiv)

g = ggtern(df,aes(DENSE,CROP,WILD))+
geom_point(alpha=0.8, aes(color=BetaDiv), size=3)+
scale_color_viridis_c(direction = -1) +
theme_bw()

g +  stat_hex_tern(aes(value=BetaDiv),binwidth=0.15,alpha=0.15,fun="mean")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: glad it was useful :)